CUDA Using shared memory for a Hadamard Product
I'm trying to understand if I am using and understanding shared memory correctly for a simple kernel that has a 1D input and a matrix input. I am doing a Hadamard Product in the sense that the 1D input is supposed to do an element-wise dot product with each row of the matrix input.
const int DSIZE = 4;
const int block_size = 2;

__global__ void hdot(const float *A, const float *B, float *C, int ds){

    int idx_A = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    int idx_B = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int idy_B = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    __shared__ float sharedA[block_size];
    __shared__ float sharedB[block_size][block_size];


    if ((idx_B < ds) && (idy_B < ds)){
        sharedA[threadIdx.x] = A[idx_A];
        sharedB[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = B[idx_B * ds + idy_B];
        __syncthreads();

        C[idx_B * ds + idy_B] = sharedA[threadIdx.x] * sharedB[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x];
    }
}

I think I am defining my shared memory correctly but I see no changes in my execution time. The numerical results are accurate though.
Many thanks!

changes compared to what?

well compared to the similar code that just has no shared memory related code. right now from what I understand I copy my data into shared memory but I want to check if my syntax is correct.

If your syntax were incorrect you would probably get either a compiler error or wrong results. For a detailed look at performance I would recommend using Nsight Compute to compare two profiles and see what changed.

@RobertCrovella sharedA is reused, but the bigger sharedB isn't.

__syncthreads(); inside that conditional is a bug/deadlock. I guess you just didn't hit it yet due to the data size being a multiple of the block size.

I hope you are not measuring time with const int block_size = 2;. I guess it should be 32 or 16 (assuming the block dimensions are block_sizexblock_size).

There is very little reuse of data with block_size = 2.  shared memory may provide a benefit when there is significant reuse of data.  And the L1 cache may be serving the same purpose.

And sharedA is not only reused when reading but also filled many times. It should be e.g. if (threadIdx.y == 0) sharedA[threadIdx.x] = A[idx_A];

If the block size is 2x2 (seems to be), that would be a generally bad configuration for performance, anyway.

More details as to what you're comparing with, the size of your data, etc... would be helpful. Here's a few thing you could look into
Shared memory is L1 Cache
On the hardware, the L1 cache and the shared memory are the same elements, the difference is simply whether you manage it yourself (shared memory) or let the runtime manage it for you (cache)
In your code, it's possible that even if you allocate to global memory, the arrays will be entirely pulled into cache on their first load and then it's as fast as shared memory. If you deal with small arrays they will only ever be loaded from global memory once.
Shared memory bank conflicts
Shared memory bank conflicts causes load and store to shared memory to be serialized, which can lead to very bad performances. You can read more about it here https://github.com/Kobzol/hardware-effects-gpu/blob/master/bank-conflicts/README.md

OP's code obviously has no bank conflicts (just for reference).

Yeah but I don't know if he just posted some minimal example so I figured it might be good for him to know :)
